# Extjs listener doesen't work on 6.2.1 modern toolikit

Tags: extjs, listener

I'm trying to add a listener to a button, using framework 6.2.1 modern toolkit, but it doesen't work, nothing happen.

```
Ext.application({
name: 'MyApp',
launch: function(){
    var view = Ext.Viewport.add({
        items: []
    })

    var button = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
        text: 'My Button',
        listeners: {
            click: function(){
                Ext.Msg.alert('Button', 'clicked');
            }
        }
    })
    view.add(button);
```

Comment: You should use `tap` instead of `click` in `listeners` or you can use `handler` on `button`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever working with a specific ExtJS toolkit, please keep in mind that the two toolkits are very different. As per the documentation, there is no click event on the button in the modern toolkit:

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.Button.html

The click event is only on the button in the classic toolkit:

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.button.Button.html#event-click

For the modern toolkit, a click on the button fires (in that order) the `release` and the `tap` event.